# Select a specific staging record from sybase table

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table with data as below:

```
Id               stage              date             Emp_id3
=====        =====           =====              =====
DEP1          new             12thmarch         33
DEP1          approval        13thmarch         22
DEP1          reject          14thmarch         77
DEP1          approval        15thmarch         66
DEP1          reject          16thmarch         65
DEP1          approval        17thmarch         87
DEP1          complete        18thmarch         99
```

I want to find that Emp_id3 who has moved the staging data from  reject to approval stage. In this case it will be 87 as it is the latest approval.
This is the audit table that has stage wise data for its master table which has current stage data. Can some one please help me with the sybase query for the same? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you described hits cumber stone Sybase ase issue, no rank function.
Bellow I have created a sample solution that involves using of temporary tables. Additional assumption is that date should be in format that ensures uniqueness ( DATETIME should be enough).

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
id VARCHAR(20),
stage VARCHAR(20),
DATE INT,
Emp_id3 INT)

INSERT INTO #temp
 select "DEP1", "new",    12,33
 union select "DEP1", "approval",13,22
 union select "DEP1", "reject", 14,77
 union select "DEP1", "approval",15,66
 union select "DEP1", "reject", 16,65
 union select "DEP1", "approval",17,87
 union select "DEP1", "complete",18,99

SELECT *, rank = identity(1) into #temp_rk FROM #temp ORDER BY DATE

SELECT changer.Emp_id3 FROM 
#temp_rk changer,#temp_rk originator
WHERE
    changer.stage="approval"
    AND originator.stage ="reject"
    AND changer.rank -1 = originator.rank
HAVING changer.rank = max(changer.rank)
```